# state not updating how to pass value to child component with updated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and was having a problem most probably due to asynchronous setState function not getting state updated.

I am setting rowvalue in the state like so:

```
rowvalue: '',
```

This is the function where I am getting my value val with value in it.

```
 getReport(ReportList,val) {
    //console.log('supply plant=' + ReportList && ReportList[0] && ReportList[0].SPCode);
    alert('Row Value=' + val);
    this.setState({ rowvalue: val });
    this.setState({ showing: true });
    this.setState({ table: false });
    this.setState({ disable: false });
    this.setState({ ReportList: rows }, this.passVariable);
  
});


 this.passVariable(val);
      }


 passVariable(val) {
    this.props.getReport(this.state.ReportList, val);
  }
```

I am trying to set the value in state and pass it to my approval PAG component like so in my render:

```
<div>
          <ApprovalPAG
            modalpag={this.state.modalpag}
            fadepag={this.state.fadepag}
            togglepag={this.togglepag}
            rowvalue={this.state.rowvalue}
          />
        </div>
```

In my ApprovalPAG component I am trying to fetch the value like so :

```
class ApprovalPAG extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: this.props.modal,
      fade: this.props.fade,
    };
  }

  click = () => {
    alert('Row ID=' + this.props.rowvalue);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.props.modalpag}
          toggle={this.props.togglepag}
          fade={this.props.fadepag}
          className={this.props.className}
        >
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.props.togglepag}>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mb-2">
              <strong>Approve/Return</strong>
            </div>
          </ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <div>
              <Label for="remarks">Remarks</Label>
              <Input type="textarea" name="text" id="remarkspag" placeholder="Add Remarks..." autoComplete="off" />
            </div>
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="success" onClick={this.click}>
              Approve
            </Button>
            <Button color="danger">Return</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ApprovalPAG;
```

On pressing the approve button I am trying to get the value of Row

However I am getting the value as undefined for this.props.rowvalue How do I work around this .Its probably because setstate is not setting the value on time. Please help I need the variable value in the component to make different operations

Comment: When `getReport` function is called?

Comment: get report function is called from another component basic table

Comment: sry this is where getReport is called passVariable(val) {
    this.props.getReport(this.state.ReportList, val);
  }

Comment: @sambit add more details to the question, when is `passVariable` called?

Comment: @Ramesh edited the question and added the details